# Wordpress - Add support for more then 2 menus

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add more menus to my website,

no matter how many items I add to 'register_nav_menus( array' I still cannot get more then 2 menus to appear in the wordpress GUI when I log in.

Does anyone know how to add more?

EDIT:

I found the answer for anyone that needs it in the future:
In your function.php file set up your register_nav_menus like this

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
function register_my_menus() {
register_nav_menus(
array(
'menu-1' => __( 'Menu 1' ),
'menu-2' => __( 'Menu 2' )
)
);
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
function register_my_menus() {
register_nav_menus(
array(
'menu-1' => _*( 'Menu 1' ),
'menu-2' => _*( 'Menu 2' )
)
);
}